# Why is my code giving me an out of range exception?

Tags: java, helper, polish

I have such a program:

```
import java.util.Scanner; import java.io.*;

class C { public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

    System.out.println("Wpisz teks do zakodowania: ");

    String tekst;
        Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);
        tekst = odczyt.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Tekst odszyfrowany:" + tekst);
        char[]alfabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
        int dlugalf=26;
        System.out.print("Tekst zaszyfrowany:");

        int a = 0;

        for(int i=0;;){

            System.out.print(tekst.charAt(a));
            a++;

        }
    }   
}
```

After its launch, you should view the question and ask you to enter text. Then it should show the sign that I wrote, and the program must load each of these letters individually, not as a whole string. But then it pops up an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOut OfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at C.main(C.java:34)
```

It is caused by an empty string. How can I get rid of it? I tried with this command:

```
if (!tekst.isEmpty() && tekst.charAt(0) == 'R');
```

but it did not work out.

Sorry for any mistakes; I do not speak English very well.

Comment: Well I don't know whatever language this post is in, but I can see you are doing an inifite loop printing by getting a char at index _a_ and _a_ will eventually go out of bounds of your array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This block of code:

```
int a=0;
for(int i=0;;){

  System.out.print(tekst.charAt(a));
  a++;
}
```

Should become

```
for(int a=0;a<tekst.length();a++){
     System.out.print(tekst.charAt(a));
}
```

As it is, your loop will try to go forever. You run out of characters in the String (when `a=tekst.length()`) and you get the exception.

Comment: Oh....                                                                                                       C.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
                for(int a=0;a<tekst.length;a++){
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable length
  location: variable tekst of type String
1 error                                                                                                                               Whats now?

Comment: @tomcio61 sorry I forgot `()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to implement text decryption with constant shift.

There is some problems with your code:

1. It doesn't take into account upper case characters and non-letters
2. Loop statement is wrong
3. There is no decryption

Here is an example

```
final int shift = 1;//any shift here
final int alhpabetLength = 'z' - 'a';
String input = scanner.nextLine();
input = input.toLowerCase();
for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
        int position = c - 'a';
        int decryptedPosition = (position + shift + alhpabetLength) % alhpabetLength;
        char decryptedC = (char)(decryptedPosition + 'a');
        System.out.print(decryptedC);
    } else {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

If you use `shift = -1` than for the encrypted line `"ifmmp!"` you will get `"hello!"`

Comment: Exactly my point. But I want the same to happen. Without the final code: D

Comment: The best way to learn something is by analyzing it. You could paste code into your project, debug it  several times line by line carefully watching values. Than you could delete pasted code and rewrite it by your own.

Comment: This is good idea.

Comment: I have this error:             C.java:32: error: possible loss of precision
                                        char decryptedP = (position + shift + da
lf) % dalf;

    ^
  required: char
  found:    int
C.java:33: error: possible loss of precision
                                        char decryptedC = decryptedP + 'a';
                                                                     ^
  required: char
  found:    int
2 errors

Comment: Updated my answer. You could mark it as an *answer* if it helps you.

Comment: Yes. all works nice.

Comment: Can you explain to me how this passage?
for (char c: input.toCharArray ()) {
if (c> = 'a' && c <= 'z') {
int position = c - 'a';
decryptedPosition = int (position + shift + alhpabetLength)% alhpabetLength;
decryptedC char = (char) (decryptedPosition + 'a');